# Check if input number has decimals

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to check if the number has decimals. Since you can't do type checking for type float or a double I came up with the the following code.

```
$('#storePaymentForm').submit(function() {
    var numberValue = document.getElementById("price").value;

    if (numberValue % 1 != 0) {
        return true;
    } 
    else {
        alert('U moet een bedrag invullen met twee nullen achter de commas!');
        return false;
    }
});
```

This code works fine when you enter a number like: `10.23` But when you enter `10.00` it returns false and shows the alert. I've tried several things, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone help me or point me in the right direction how I can check if the number has decimals. And make sure when a user enters `10.00` it returns true instead of false(which is the case right now). The input field is of type number. 
The input field looks like this:
 `<input type="number" id="price" required name="price" min="0" value="0.00" step=".01">`

Comment: Since the value is a string, you should really do pattern matching.

Comment: You could `!isNaN(numberValue) && numberValue.includes(".")` This won't allow multiple `.` characters unlike `indexOf`

Comment: You have to distinguish between mathematical numbers, and Strings, which represent that numbers. You say, that "10" is not the same as "10.00", so you are not talking about Integer / non-integer detection, but a detection, if a string contains a dot character: ".", am I right? Input type=number always returns a mathematical number, there is no way to tell if "10" or "10.00" is displayed inside.

Answer (score -1):

As the value is of type string, you could try working out if it is **not** a decimal:

```
string.indexOf(".") == -1;
```